# Dash/Plotly - How do i turn off clearing value from dropdowns when using multi true?

Tags: plotly-dash

Basically, I'd like to know if it is possible to make sure a value is always selected in the dropdowns so a graph view is always available?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your callback that generates your figures based on the dropdowns, you can simply add a check that accounts for when no dropdown options are selected.

Since you've set `multi=True` the `value` property of your dropdown will always be a list:

```
if not dropdown_values:
    # The dropdown_values list is empty, return your graphs...
```

If you don't like the default `Select...` placeholder you can change it with the `placeholder` argument of `dcc.Dropdown`.

Alternatively if you want a certain option to stay active you could add this option back after it is cleared or after every option is cleared:

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input, State

default_dropdown_value = "MTL"

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dcc.Dropdown(
    id="dropdown",
    options=[
        {"label": "New York City", "value": "NYC"},
        {"label": "Montreal", "value": "MTL"},
        {"label": "San Francisco", "value": "SF"},
    ],
    value=[default_dropdown_value],
    multi=True,
)


@app.callback(Output("dropdown", "value"), Input("dropdown", "value"))
def dropdown_callback(dropdown_value):
    if not dropdown_value:
        return [default_dropdown_value]
    return dropdown_value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Or you could add some css that targets the first option and disables pointer events:

```
.Select-multi-value-wrapper .Select-value:first-child {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or you could hide `x`'s entirely. These have a `Select-value-icon` class you could target them with.